# Serverless invoke test returns status 500 when using Vandium: Expected event type of apigateway but identified as unknown

Tags: node.js, testing, lambda, serverless-framework

When running `serverless invoke test` and using [Vandium](https://github.com/vandium-io/vandium-node), I'm getting `Status Code 500` and Error:

```
{"type":"Error","message":"Expected event type of apigateway but identified as unknown”}
```

Here is the code to reproduce the problem. First, working example (without Vandium):

**time/handler.js**:

```
'use strict';

module.exports.endpoint =

(event, context, callback) => {
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: `Hello, the current time is ${new Date().toTimeString()}.`,
        }),
    };

    callback(null, response);
}
```

**serverless.yml**:

```
service: serverless-starter

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
functions:
  currentTime:
    handler: time/handler.endpoint
    events:
      - http:
          path: ping
          method: get
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-mocha-plugin
```

Finally, autogenerated test code that checks status code:
**test/currentTime.js**:

```
'use strict';

// tests for currentTime
// Generated by serverless-mocha-plugin

const mochaPlugin = require('serverless-mocha-plugin');
const expect = mochaPlugin.chai.expect;
let wrapped = mochaPlugin.getWrapper('currentTime', '/time/handler.js', 'endpoint');

describe('currentTime', () => {
  before((done) => {
    done();
  });

  it('implement tests here', () => {
    return wrapped.run({}).then((response) => {
        const body = JSON.parse(response.body);
        expect(response.statusCode).to.be.equal(200);
    });
  });
});
```

This works fine. I can start the server: `serverless offline start` and I'm able to get the http://localhost:3000/ping endpoint fine with curl or POSTMAN.

If I run `serverless invoke test` then the test runs fine. No problems up to this point.

Now, when I refactor the code and use Vandium:
**time/handler.js**:

```
'use strict';

const vandium = require('vandium');

module.exports.endpoint = vandium.api()
        .GET((event) => {
            return {
                "id": "12345",
                "name": "john.doe"
            };
        }
    )
```

Then everything works fine, i.e. I can start the server and connect to endpoint with curl or POSTMAN.

Yet, when I run the test again `serverless invoke test` then instead of status code 200, I get 500 and error:

`{"type":"Error","message":"Expected event type of apigateway but identified as unknown”}`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Create a json file with an APIGatewayEvent object or one of the supported aws events. Then run serverless with option -p or -d (see: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/invoke-local#options)

```
sls invoke local -f hello -p path-to-json.json
```

Take a look at https://github.com/vandium-io/lambda-event-identifier/blob/master/lib/identify.js for more information